# How do I stop my LED strip from getting too hot?

Tags: led

When I plug A 12V DC 8" LED strip into my car, it gets too hot to touch, but when I plug it into A 110V AC to 12V DC 120mA transformer, it works great; "cool to the touch".

So do I go buy a resister and put it in line? If so, what resister do I ask for and which band goes to the LED side?

Comment: What are the specifications of your led strip? Colour, amount of LEDs/m, length

Comment: Any specs available? Good data allows good answers.The strip is NOT a genuinely rated 12V one for whatever reason - the transformer has a limited power capacity so is not putting too much energy into the strip.  | Transformer is capable of 12V x 0.12A (really? - that's VERY low) = 1.44 Watt.Try a R = V/I = 6/0.12 =~ 47 Ohm 5 Watt resistor in series with the strip.

Comment: @russell considering 60 led per meter strips have 20 3-led segments at ~20mA each, an 8" section is about 18 leds or 6 segments. 120mA * 12V sounds right.

Comment: As suggested, car "12v" volt is actually 13.7volts! That is why its getting hot. The reason its 13.7~~ish volts is because when you start to turn allot of stuff on the voltage will drop to about 12.5 volts. But in modern cars this doesnt happen anymore.

Comment: @Passerby - I was more thinking that a 12V plug pack that made 120 mA was unusually low. It obviously can happen but most are liable to be 500 mA or 1A rated.

Answer (score 3):

A "12V" automotive electrical system generally supplies about 14V +/- 0.5V when the motor is running. Try putting some series 1N400x (where x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 or 7) diodes in series with the strip. Each will drop about 0.6V, so three or four of them in series should make quite a difference. They're inexpensive, so get a bunch.

The current is not simply predicted by Ohms law because the LED strip is a nonlinear load- the current rises much more quickly with increasing voltage than would the current through a resistor.

Answer (score -2):

Any specs available? Good data allows good answers.

It is extremely likely that the strip is NOT a genuinely rated 12V one for whatever reason - the transformer has a limited power capacity so is not putting too much energy into the strip.  This is demonstrated by the fact that a 12V supply capable of providing more current than needed so that it does not "droop" causes heating problems. If the power pack was able to provide rated current at 12V + then similar heating results should occur.

You state that the "transformer" is capable of 12V x 0.12A which is extremely low for a 12V supply. 12v x 0.12A =  1.44 Watt. As a single LED at 20 mA is rated at typicall 40 to 60 mW, a total of 1.44 Watt would only power 24 to 36 LEDs. How many are there, and what colour?

Let's assume to start that the strip runs at 6V and draws 120 mA.
Try a resistor such that R = V/I = 6/0.12 =~ 47 Ohm
A 1 W resistor would do BUT a 5 Watt resistor is safer and not expensive.
Place resistor in series with the strip.
If too dim reduce resistor value.

Record strip voltage when running OK. 
Record resistor value.
Report back.