# 12 VDC LED strips get too hot

Tags: led, resistors, amperage

Package reads "2 8in 12vdc LED strips".

Plugged into a car they get hot enough to melt.
Plugged into a 12vdc 120mA transformer they work great.

What resistor do I need to bring car amperage down to 120mA?

Comment: What is the Forward voltage drop of your LED's.

Comment: Can you give a link to the product description? One possibility is that the 12VDC 120mA transformer is not entirely honest about its specification (it could for instance be 120mA current limited).

Comment: Car "12v" batteries are usually more like 14V or more when being charged from the alternator.

Comment: You had two perfectly good answers when this was asked in MY {**here**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112324/how-do-i-stop-my-led-strip-from-getting-too-hot/112349#112349) - why did you not try them? Both MUST work if followed as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certain that the string draws more than 120 mA from the transformer.
It is possible that you have misread the transformer current rating. This is dealt with below.

Your string will almost certainly have multiple groups of 3 LEDs. Occasionally they are in one package but usually you get 3 LEDs from 12V to ground with a single common resistor per group. Occasionally you see groups with two resistors per group, presumably to spread the power dissipation amongst several resistors. So ...

If you can measure string current with car and adapter used, do so.
Also measure the voltage input at the connection point to the string in each case.
Go to "**Jump to here if currents known**" below

Otherwise - voltage measurements needed. Any DMM (digital multimeter) will do.

Identify what constitutes a group.

Count number of groups total.

Identify a series resistor.
Determine its value either from a marking on it or by measuring the resistance with an Ohmmeter with power turned off. 
[Typical values may be 5 Ohms to 200 Ohms. Range is wider than expected because they probably put several LEDS per package. This method handles that OK.]

Apply 12V from car.

Measure voltage across the above resistor = Vr.
Measure voltage input to string at input point. Call this Vcar. Nominally 12V but may not be.

Turn off power.

Current in one group = V/R from above
eg = V = 3V and R = 20 Ohms then
Igroup = V/R = 3 / .020 = 150 mA.
Hopefully it will be rather less.

Total current = Groups x Igroup
Call this Icar

Repeat the exercise using the 12V supply. This will give you an idea of the current actually being drawn from the nominally 120 mA supply.
Call this Iadapter

Measure the voltage at the power supply connection point as it will be "loaded down" by the string. Call this Vadapter. If it was not loaded down the current would be the same as when connected to the car.

**Jump to here if currents known**

Now:

The aim is to reduce string voltage to adapter equivalent. 
So you need to "drop" Vcar - Vadapter.
R = V/I = (Vcar-Vadapter) / I adapter
= resistor to use.

Power dissipation in resistor = I^2 x R = Iadapter^2 x R
Use a resistor with a somewhat higher wattage rating than this. Bigger than needed is OK.

Answer (score 0):

A running motor could make car generator generate nearly 14 volt power. So if your 12V/120mA DC transformer can work well, then a 15 to 30 Ohm 1/2W resistor will be OK.

Comment: +1 as it did not deserve an umcommented down vote. It's probably wise to show your thinking as otherwise people with little understanding may think your answer is arbitary - which it's not. ie IF the strip draws 120 mA then a 15 Ohm resistor will drop V = IR = 0.120 A x 15 R = 1.8V and a 30 R will drop 3.6V. So the 14V car voltage will be reduced to about 12.2 mV with 15 Ohms. | Note that your resistor wattage is marginal - @ 120 mA dissipation with 15R P = 200mW and 30R ~= 400 mW so a 1 Watt R is safer.